# JsonServiceExporter Logging

Tags: java, json, spring, logging, javabeans

I would like to log all JSON requests and responses for the following bean:

```
<bean name="/RPC.json" class="com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonServiceExporter">
<property name="service" ref="RPC"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="interfaces.RPC"/>
</bean>
```

I currently do not know how to do it.